# Does this sentence contain an introductory clause

Tags: grammar, word-usage

> Choosing a film school is always tough, you have to weigh up location, course choice, and fees to name a few.

And could this sentence  take a semi colon after tough or a conjunction. Can **you** not be the 'subject' of an independent clause.

> You hurt my feelings- for instance.

Or:

> There's so much to consider when choosing a film school; you also have to weigh up the fee too.

Comment: Quite possibly a duplicate of [Can a declarative independent clause be considered an introductory element?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/182789/can-a-declarative-independent-clause-be-considered-an-introductory-element). The term 'introductory clause' is probably given different definitions by different pundits. Here, 'Choosing a film school is always tough' is certainly an [independent] clause and certainly is followed by a development of the theme. But I'd say that it is the main statement here, so wouldn't use the term 'introductory clause'. But I'd use a colon/dash after it.

Comment: You need to sort out your sentence structure before you can ask this question.  “Choosing ...tough” is a simple sentence and should end with a full stop, or (conceivably, a full colon.

Comment: The second sentence should use comma, not hyphen.

Comment: Or was "for instance" supposed to be part of the question, not the sentence you're asking about? It's hard to understand a question about sentences if you don't mark it up properly, I had to guess how to reformat it.

Answer (score 2):

[1] *Choosing a film school is always tough*

is an **independent clause**.

[2] *choosing a film school*

is a **gerund-participal clause** which here funtions as the **subject** of [1]. Note that according to [CGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521431468) (p. 333), [2] is a **clause**, and not a noun phrase (NP). Thus, although the subject of a sentence is *usually* realized by an NP, it can also be realized by certain types of clauses.

Next, *is* the verb, and *always tough* is an adjective phrase functioning as a predicative complement of *is*.

The other clause,

[3] *you have to weigh up location, course choice, and fees, to name a few [factors],*

is also an independent clause.

Since these are two independent clauses, if you want to join them into a single sentence, you need to either coordinate them (using *and*, *so*, *therefore*, etc.) or connect them via a semi-colon, like you've done in your final example.

**An *introductory clause*?**

Although Edwin Ashworth is certainly right when he says that different sources may mean different things by the term *introductory clause*, I do think this definition from Grammarly is a very common one, and, in particular, the one you had in mind (see [here](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/commas-after-introductory-clauses/)):

> Introductory clauses are dependent clauses that are often found at the beginning of the sentence (although they can be moved to the end of the sentence, too, without confusing the meaning of the sentence).

I *think* what happened here is that you *thought* that [1] is a dependent clause, probably because it starts with a gerund-participial, *choosing*. Then, since in that case it would be a **fronted** dependent clause, you called it an 'introductory clause'.

However, as I explained above, [1] is in fact an independent clause.